# unoconv error 1287 / ErrorCodeIOException on jaunty

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice.org, ubuntu-9.10

I installed openoffice headless on jaunty, but unoconv won't work via SSH. Any idea?

```
unoconv: UnoException during conversion in <class '__main__.com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException'>: 
ERROR: The provided document cannot be converted to the desired format. (code: 1287)
```

I started

```
unoconv -l &
```

before

Comment: it seems like starting the listener like this: soffice -display :0.0 -norestore -headless  "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" solves the problem. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501440

Answer (score 0):

First check the document u converting is in supported formats, if doesnt work kill the existing unoconv and restart listener with unoconv --listner &